# How to run msfconsole within any directory?

Tags: arch-linux, alias, metasploit

I just installed [metasploit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Metasploit_Framework). The issue is I can only run `./msfconsole` in installation directory which is `/opt/framework/metasploit-framework`.

When I run `msfconsole` in another directory, I get this error:

```
Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

In my .bashrc file :

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" 
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin"
export PATH="$(ruby -e 'print Gem.user_dir')/bin:$PATH"

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/framework/metasploit-framework
alias msfconsole="./msfconsole --quiet -x \"db_connect ${USER}@msf\""
```

My solution so far (I have to `exit` to `/opt/framework/metasploit-framework` though) :

```
alias msfconsole="cd /opt/framework/metasploit-framework && ./msfconsole --quiet -x \"db_connect ${USER}@msf\""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve by adding this line to my `.bashrc`:

```
alias msfconsole="cd /opt/framework/metasploit-framework && ./msfconsole --quiet -x \"db_connect ${USER}@msf\ && cd -""
```

Comment: Please remember to come back and [accept](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) this answer when the system allows you to by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered. Και καλώς ήρθες!

Answer (score 0):

Your alias is wrong. The leading `./` means "do this in the current directory". If you remove it it should work.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/framework/metasploit-framework
alias msfconsole="msfconsole --quiet -x \"db_connect ${USER}@msf\""
```

Comment: I alreay tried `alias msfconsole="msfconsole --quiet -x \"db_connect ${USER}@msf\"" ` .It doesn't work.

Comment: Have you reloaded ("sourced") `.bashrc` before trying again? Either spawn a new shell (e.g. a new terminal window if using X), or use `source ~/.bashrc` (which can be shortened to `. ~/.bashrc`).

Comment: I'd guess that you need to either set `GEM_PATH` to include the gems installed locally by metasploit, or do as the error says and install the gems globally.

Comment: I edited the question.